# Solving $k e^{k\theta+2k\pi} \cos \theta - e^{k\theta+2k\pi} \sin \theta + \sin \theta = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation

I have been trying to solve this equation that involves exponentiation and trigonometry.

$$k e^{k\theta+2k\pi} \cos \theta - e^{k\theta+2k\pi} \sin \theta + \sin \theta = 0$$

Where $k$ is a non-integer constant and $\theta$ is a variable. I need to solve this for $\theta$.

This equation is for $dx/d\theta$ in a modified logarithmic spiral and I try to determine when the spiral tangent line is vertical.

I have tried a few things but have been unable to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What's teh equation of your original spiral? And is there a reason to expect some nice solutions in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: This is transcendetal equation so there is no closed-form for solution. If you need numerical value of $\theta$ I recommend using plotting or numerical methods.

Comment: Looks like $r=\exp(k\theta+2k\pi)-1$. One can simplify equation with substitution $\theta=t-2\pi$, then $ke^{kt}\cos t-e^{kt}\sin t+\sin t=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A @Ivan Kaznacheyeu commented, using $\theta=t-2\pi$, we need to find the zeros of function
$$f(t)=e^{k t} (k \cos (t)-\sin (t))+\sin (t)$$ for, I presume, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

The first thing which is interesting to look at is the zero level curve of $f(t)$ (have loook [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5B++E%5E%28k+t%29+%28k+Cos%5Bt%5D+-+Sin%5Bt%5D%29+%2B+Sin%5Bt%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+10%7D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+2+Pi%7D%5D)). I shall suppose that we are concerned by the root for $t \in (0,\pi)$.

Assuming $k>0$, the first estimate of the solution is
$$t_0=\tan ^{-1}(k)$$
The first iterate of Newton method is
$$t_{(2)}=\tan ^{-1}(k)+\frac{k}{\left(k^2+1\right) e^{k \tan ^{-1}(k)}-1}$$

Since
$$f(t_0) \times f''(t_0)=-k^2 \left(\frac{1}{k^2+1}+2 e^{k \tan ^{-1}(k)}\right)~~< ~~0$$ by Darboux theorem, $t_{(2)}$ is an overestimate of the solution.

This could be improved using instead the first iterate of Halley method

$$t_{(3)}=\tan ^{-1}(k)+\frac{2 k \left(\left(k^2+1\right) e^{k \tan ^{-1}(k)}-1\right)}{k^2+2
   \left(k^2+1\right) e^{k \tan ^{-1}(k)} \left(k^2+\left(k^2+1\right) e^{k \tan
   ^{-1}(k)}-2\right)+2}$$

We could still improve computing $t_{(4)}$, the first interate of Householder method (formula not typed here since bit too long for the page) and even for the next higher orders. All the expressions of $t_{(n)}$ are fully explicit in terms of $k$ and basic functions of it.

This does not look too bad, at least for $k\geq $ as shown below

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
k & t_{(2)} & t_{(3)}  & t_{(4)} & t_{(5)}& t_{(6)}& \text{solution} \\
 1.00 & 1.0806830 & 0.9924595 & 1.0077207 & 1.0053055 & 1.0056672 &   1.0056210 \\
 1.25 & 1.0784245 & 1.0387710 & 1.0435558 & 1.0430623 & 1.0431095 &   1.0431055 \\
 1.50 & 1.0964786 & 1.0783341 & 1.0798824 & 1.0797763 & 1.0797828 &   1.0797827 \\
 1.75 & 1.1228185 & 1.1145118 & 1.1150178 & 1.1149943 & 1.1149953 &   1.1149953 \\
 2.00 & 1.1518166 & 1.1480411 & 1.1482055 & 1.1482002 & 1.1482004 &   1.1482004 \\
 2.25 & 1.1806697 & 1.1789696 & 1.1790222 & 1.1790211 & 1.1790211 &   1.1790211 \\
 2.50 & 1.2080044 & 1.2072455 & 1.2072621 & 1.2072619 & 1.2072619 &   1.2072619 \\
 2.75 & 1.2332202 & 1.2328839 & 1.2328890 & 1.2328890 & 1.2328890 &   1.2328893 \\
 3.00 & 1.2561380 & 1.2559898 & 1.2559914 & 1.2559913 & 1.2559913 &   1.2559914 \\
 3.25 & 1.2768018 & 1.2767367 & 1.2767372 & 1.2767372 & 1.2767372 &   1.2767372 \\
 3.50 & 1.2953646 & 1.2953361 & 1.2953362 & 1.2953362 & 1.2953362 &   1.2953362 \\
 3.75 & 1.3120244 & 1.3120119 & 1.3120119 & 1.3120119 & 1.3120119 &   1.3120119 \\
 4.00 & 1.3269887 & 1.3269832 & 1.3269832 & 1.3269832 & 1.3269832 &   1.3269832 \\
 4.25 & 1.3404565 & 1.3404541 & 1.3404541 & 1.3404541 & 1.3404541 &   1.3404541 \\
 4.50 & 1.3526098 & 1.3526087 & 1.3526087 & 1.3526087 & 1.3526087 &   1.3526087 \\
 4.75 & 1.3636107 & 1.3636102 & 1.3636102 & 1.3636102 & 1.3636102 &   1.3636102 \\
 5.00 & 1.3736011 & 1.3736009 & 1.3736009 & 1.3736009 & 1.3736009 &   1.3736011
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For the fun, we also could write is that the solution is the (impossible) inverse of
$$k=\tan(t)+\frac 1 t W\left(-t \,\tan (t)\,e^{-t\, \tan (t)} \right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

But this shows that, for $k>0$ there is no solution smaller than the root of
$$t \, \tan(t)=1 $$ that is to say $t=0.8603335890\cdots$